# How to get the number of total scattergather items in Snakemake scatter/gather?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm trying out Snakemake's scatter/gather inbuilts but am stumbling over how to get the number of total splits configured.

The documentation doesn't mention how I can access that variable as defined in the workflow or passed through CLI.

Docs say I should define a scattergather directive:

```
scattergather:
    split=8
```

But how do I get the value of `split` which is `8` in this case inside my split rule where I would assign it to `params.split_total`?

```
rule split:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: scatter.split("splitted/{scatteritem}.txt")
    params: split_total = config["scattergather"]["split"]
    shell: "split -l {params.split_total} input"
```

This fails with: `KeyError 'scattergather'`

Am I missing something obvious? This is the docs I'm looking at: KeyError in line 48 of /Users/corneliusromer/code/ncov-ingest/workflow/snakemake_rules/curate.smk:
2 'scattergather'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility of accessing specific setting via `workflow` internal property `._scatter`:

```py
scattergather:
    split=8

# downstream rule can refer to the python variable
rule split:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: scatter.split("splitted/{scatteritem}.txt")
    params: split_total = workflow._scatter["split"]
    shell: "split -l {params.split_total} input"
```

This will dynamically change when CLI param `set-scatter` is provided.

For other cases, one could leverage python. In the snippet below this is done via setting a specific value, however any valid way to set/obtain value in python will work:

```py
# python variable/label
split_total = 8

scattergather:
    split=split_total

# downstream rule can refer to the python variable
rule split:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: scatter.split("splitted/{scatteritem}.txt")
    params: split_total = split_total
    shell: "split -l {params.split_total} input"
```

Comment: Ah nice, so the solution is `worfklow._scatter["split"]`, would be nice if this was documented, see https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1961
Your first answer has the problem that it doesn't pick up CLI overwrite through `--set-scatter split=2` if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: That is correct, the first snippet doesn't pick up CLI-based change, I will update the answer.